# Update of packages in Ubuntu 16.04 fail

Tags: 16.04

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Does not work.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific and give some more details about your problem. How your question is worded right now, I can't fully understand what you are asking. As well, why did you tag 12.04 if you are looking for a 16.04 answer?

Comment: Please consider  to [edit] your question and add more description about your problem.

Comment: Provide information as text rather than image(s) (readable, searchable, etc).

Comment: Try opening up Software & Updates > Download from: and pick a different server. Then reload sources & see.

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get --fix-missing`

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your system with the following commands:

remove unneeded packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

get rid of partial packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

get rid of 'orphaned' packages:

```
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
```

remove configurations files of uninstalled packages:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

clean out unused package stuff (cache)

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

update your system about the newest available packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install the newest available packages on your system:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now try to install your stuff again:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

If this does not work, install the missing dependent packages manually...like:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu... and the others similarly, then run again:
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Forcing something with -f is never a very good idea unless you know exactly what you do...

Answer (score 0):

You must update package lists with this option and then run install:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Comment: I don't think this will fix 403 errors.